# Erro ao conectar no banco de dados via Seriate Node JS

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, aplicação-web, heroku

Quando conecto ao meu banco de dados localmente ele funciona normalmente. Porém quando dou deploy na Heroku me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Request Error: No connection is specified for that request
```

O meu objeto de configuração está da seguinte forma:

```
var sql = require("seriate");

var config = {
    "server": "SERVER",
    "user": "USER_NAME",
    "password": "PASSWORD",
    "database": "DATABASE_NAME",
    "pool": {
      "max": 10,
      "min": 4,
      "idleTimeoutMillis": 60000
    }
};


sql.setDefaultConfig(config);

module.exports = sql
```

As credenciais estão corretas, uma vez que eu consigo me conectar ao banco localmente. Se alguém tiver algo a acrescentar ja irá me ajudar muito, estou a horas pesquisando e tentando solucionar e nada.

Answer (score 0):

Na [documentação](https://openbase.io/js/seriate/documentation) a estrutura do config tá assim:

```
{
    "name": "default",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "12345", // find the port of your instance in the SQL Server Configuration Manager
    "user": "nodejs",
    "password": "mypassword",
    "database": "master",
    "pool": {
        "max": 10,
        "min": 4,
        "idleTimeoutMillis": 30000
    }
}
```

Experimente trocar `"server"` por `"host"`

O resultado ficaria assim:

```
var sql = require("seriate");

var config = {
    "host": "SERVER",
    "user": "USER_NAME",
    "password": "PASSWORD",
    "database": "DATABASE_NAME",
    "pool": {
      "max": 10,
      "min": 4,
      "idleTimeoutMillis": 60000
    }
};


sql.setDefaultConfig(config);

module.exports = sql
```